# Dynamically Load Styles and Scripts from Theme Functions.php

Tags: pages, page-template, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I am attempting to dynamically load stylesheets and scripts based on the template name. So if I have a template named `page-signup.php` then it will load the corresponding stylesheet `page-signup.css` and `page-signup.js` if they exist for that page from a specific directory in my theme folder.

Here is what I have so far in functions.php of my theme. It does not currently load any styles or scripts when the css and js files are present in the proper directory:

```
/**
 * Auto loads scripts and styles based on the page name if they exist.
 */
function mytheme_bootstrap_page_resources() {
    if( is_page_template() ) {
        $page_template = basename( get_page_template(), '.php' );
        $css_file_path = get_template_directory() . "/css/pages/$page_template.css";
        $js_file_path = get_template_directory() . "/js/pages/$page_template.js";
        $css_file_uri = get_template_directory_uri() . "/css/pages/$page_template.css";
        $js_file_uri = get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/pages/$page_template.js";

        if(file_exists($css_file_path)){
            wp_enqueue_style($page_template, $css_file_uri);
        }

        if(file_exists($js_file_path)){
            wp_enqueue_script($page_template, $js_file_uri);
        }
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_bootstrap_page_resources');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple issues here...

First, the `init` hook is too early for WordPress to know which page template you're going to be using.  (So the `is_page_template()` function will always return false).

Just go ahead and hook your function to `wp_enqueue_scripts` (which you're probably already doing for your global CSS / JavaScript).  *And then* check for the page template and run your logic inside that function.

Second, `get_template_directory_uri()` will return the web URL of your file and PHP's `file_exists` expects a directory path on disk (not a URL).  Use the `get_template_directory()` function to get that path, and enqueue it with `get_template_directory_uri()`.

Here's a working example, including the proper hook into `wp_enqueue_scripts` but you'll want to move the *contents* of `load_resources()` into your own function in your theme that's already hooked.

```
function load_resources() {
    if( is_page_template() ) {
        $page_template = basename( get_page_template(), '.php' );
        $css_file_path = get_template_directory() . '/css/pages/' . $page_template . '.css';
        $js_file_path = get_template_directory() . '/js/pages/' . $page_template . '.js';
        $css_file_uri = get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/pages/' . $page_template . '.css';
        $js_file_uri = get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/pages/' . $page_template . '.js';

        if(file_exists($css_file_path)){
            wp_enqueue_style($page_template, $css_file_uri);
        }

        if(file_exists($js_file_path)){
            wp_enqueue_script($page_template, $js_file_uri);
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_resources' );
```

Comment: Thanks for catching all those errors. It got me a lot closer. I am still unable to get css/pages/page-signup.css or js/pages/page-signup.js to load for pages/page-signup.php.

Comment: Are you getting any specific errors (such as 404 errors)?  Meaning, is WordPress trying to load *something* but the path or filename are wrong?  Also, ensure you are definitely using the template you think you're using on that specific page you're testing on.  I added this code to a test installation and it worked for me.

Comment: Also, as a starting point, that entire snippet should be workable if placed in your `functions.php` file... Rather than trying to adapt it into your current theme.  (Again, just as a test).

Comment: I got xdebug setup and I was able to hit the function. is_page_template() is false. When I go inside it, the $page_template variable is an empty string when I hit this line: $page_template = get_page_template_slug( get_queried_object_id() );

Mmmmh. My custom templates are not stored in the root of my theme folder so maybe that's why they aren't getting picked up by this function? I made sure the page I am testing against is linked to this template.

Comment: @AdamFisher Yes, that's possible. Just as a test you can move your template into the root of the theme folder and name it `page-signup.php`. Ensure you have a comment at the top with `/* Template Name: Signup */` and choose that template for the test page under the "Page Template" dropdown.

Comment: I finally figured out xdebug and saw that I needed to use get_stylesheet_directory() and get_stylesheet_directory_uri() because my theme is a child theme. The functions in your answer are for a normal non-child theme.